# How to pass XDocument from one controller to another in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetCustomerDetails(Customer customer)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    XDocument document = customer.GetAccountDetail(customer.AccountNumber);

    Response.write(document);

}
```

How to pass this document to other controller so that to display few xml values in other view.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "pass to another controller".  And it's *really* not clear why you're using `Response.Write()` instead of just returning an `ActionResult`.  What specifically are you trying to accomplish?  Please describe the context of the problem.

Comment: Response.write () i used to check whether i am getting xml values from the service...and I need to fetch few values from this xml document and show in other User Interface. So i need to pass this xml document to other controller

Comment: I suspect your confusion is coming from some fundamental misunderstandings of how an ASP.NET MVC web application works.  How is the "other controller" involved in any way here?  This action is (*very* incorrectly, by the way) returning a response to the user as expected.  So what is making a request to the other controller?  Can't that other request get the "document" the same way this one does?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but guessing from the context, you can store the document in cache and retrieve it wherever you want in the whole application.
eg:
controller 1
**storing document**
httpcontext.cache["xml"]=document;

Controller 2

**retrieving it**
var doc=httpcontxt.cache.get("xml");
XDocument doc= Xdocument.Parse(doc);

Comment: correction: var doc= HttpContext.Cache["xml"]; XDocument doc= Xdocument.Parse(doc.ToString());